# Mysqli SELECT only works with numbers, not working with letters

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this query:

```
SELECT users.email
FROM prefix_users as users
LEFT JOIN prefix_user_permission_matches as matches ON users.id = 
matches.user_id
LEFT JOIN prefix_permissions as permissions ON permissions.id = matches.permission_id
WHERE permissions.name IN ($entreprise)
```

The query only works when the search/WHERE parameter $entreprise is numerical, but it does not work with letters.

Any idea why?

I am using the query in PHP with prepared statement. Sorry if the question is poorly written, let me know if you want more info.

Comment: letters need quoting; that's why it's not working

Comment: Since you're using prepared statements, converting that to `IN (?)` using a placeholder value and then binding `$enterprise` to that value will probably fix this problem.